# How to create constraints on query strings in Zend Framework 2?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2, constraints

I am using ZF2 and I would like to know if there is a way to constraint the possible query strings in a GET request. For instance, imagine that I have the /ajax/users and I want to filter some users by name and city (i.e. /ajax/users?city=X&country=Y) but I want to forbid other queries (e.g. /ajax/users?name=Z). 
Is there a way to do this using ZF2 (without coding a function that checks for valid values)?

I was thinking in using Zend 2 router and create a constraint in this route, but I also want that it be order agnostic (i.e. I want to be able to do ajax/users?city=X&country=Y and ajax/users/country=Y&city=X) and it seems that using the routing constraints it will be dependent on the specified order

Comment: what have you tried yet ? Show us some code so that we can help you.
You can fetch the request data and define a specific get key to remove the cities or you can add a '!' in front of the cities you don't want and parse them. There are a lot of possible solutions.Choose one,  Try it, and we'll help you deal with it.

Comment: You can't specify query parameter constraints in the router config. The validation will have to occur in the controller.

Comment: I think that I found a way to do it but I would like to know if it is the cleanest way:
In the fieldset for a data filtering form I specified an array of possible params and in the controller I have a function which removes from params all the values that arent in the params defined. This way the params just contain the needed values, having it be passed to doctrine to be used in where clause.

What do you think of this approach?

Comment: Your form will take care of that. The validated input removes the wrong ones and returns only the query params that are part of your field.